# Select in Access with iif + is null, sort not possible

Tags: iif

this query dose not work with the **order by**. i should remove the order by then there is no sort by client name

```
Select Distinct
  Cat.Mz_Client,
  IIf(cl.Client_Name Is Null, Cat.Mz_Client, cl.Client_Name) AS Client_Name
from
  MzCatalog Cat
Left Join tbClient cl On
  Cat.Mz_Client = cl.Client_Code
Where Mz_Client Is Not NULL
Order by Client_Name
```

is there a way to run it in MsAccess??